# Telerik radGrid Is there a way to not have edit form embedded in middle of grid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying out the RadGridControl.  I was hoping to use the "Edit" column they have and build my own panel below the RadGrid for adding/updating data.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I can't get the grid to stop handling my "Edit' click and expanding.

Comment: Are you talking about [Grid - Form Template Edit Form](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx)? If not, please post your mark up/screenshot.

Comment: Nope, I am specifically attempting to create my own area outside the radgrid.  I simply want the grid to display data and show the "edit" column.

Comment: Actually, i found what i was looking for.  HTH someone.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/insert-update-delete-client/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular ButtonColumn and capture the click event in ItemCommand.

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn 
   ButtonType="ImageButton" 
   CommandName="Update" 
   ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.png"
   Text="Click to edit" 
   UniqueName="Edit" 
   HeaderText="Edit">
</telerik:GridButtonColumn>

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Update")
   {
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues
         [e.Item.ItemIndex]["Id"]);    

      YourEditPanel.Visible = true;
   }
}
```